# What is the difference between Series.replace and Series.str.replace?

Tags: python, pandas, replace

Oftentimes I am tasked with performing some sort of replace or substitution operation on data in a Series or DataFrames column(s).

For example, given a Series of strings,

```
s = pd.Series(['foo', 'another foo bar', 'baz'])

0                foo
1    another foo bar
2                baz
dtype: object
```

The goal would be to replace all occurrences of "foo" with "bar", to get

```
0                bar
1    another bar bar
2                baz
Name: A, dtype: object
```

At this point I am usually confused as there are two options I can use to solve this: `replace`, and `str.replace`. The confusion arises from the fact that I am unsure as to which is the right method to use, or what the difference (if any) between them is.

What are the main differences between `replace` and `str.replace`, and what are the benefits/caveats of using either?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Skip to the TLDR; at the bottom of this answer for a brief summary of
> the differences.

It is easy to understand the difference if you think of these two methods in terms of their utility.

**[`.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)** is a method with a *very* specific purpose—to perform string or regex substitution on *string* data.

OTOH, **[`.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)** is more of an all-purpose [Swiss Army knife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Army_knife) which can replace *anything* with *anything else* (and yes, this includes string and regex).

Consider the simple DataFrame below, this will form the basis of our forthcoming discussion.

```
# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['foo', 'another foo bar', 'baz'],
    'B': [0, 1, 0]
})
df

                 A  B
0              foo  0
1  another foo bar  1
2              baz  0
```

The main differences between the two functions can be summarised in terms of

1. Purpose
2. Usage
3. Default behavior

---

**Use `str.replace` for substring replacements on a single string column, and `replace` for any general replacement on one or more columns.**

The docs market `str.replace` as a method for "simple string replacement", so this should be your first choice when performing string/regex substitution on a pandas Series or column—think of it as a "vectorised" equivalent to python's string `replace()` function (or `re.sub()` to be more accurate).

```
# simple substring replacement
df['A'].str.replace('foo', 'bar', regex=False)

0                bar
1    another bar bar
2                baz
Name: A, dtype: object

# simple regex replacement
df['A'].str.replace('ba.', 'xyz')

0                foo
1    another foo xyz
2                xyz
Name: A, dtype: object
```

`replace` works for string as well as non-string replacement. What's more, it is also meant to **work for multiple columns at a time (you can access `replace` as a DataFrame method `df.replace()` as well, if you need to replace values across the entire DataFrame.

```
# DataFrame-wide replacement
df.replace({'foo': 'bar', 1: -1})

                 A  B
0              bar  0
1  another foo bar -1
2              baz  0
```

---

**`str.replace` can replace one thing at a time. `replace` lets you perform multiple independent replacements, i.e., replace many things at once.**

You can only specify a single substring or regex pattern to `str.replace`. `repl` can be a callable (see the docs), so there's room to get creative with regex to somewhat simulate multiple substring replacements, but these solutions are hacky at best).

A common pandaic (pandorable, pandonic) pattern is to use `str.replace` to remove multiple unwanted substrings by pipe-separating substrings using the regex OR pipe `|`, and the replacement string is `''` (the empty string).

`replace` should be preferred when you have *multiple independent* replacements of the form `{'pat1': 'repl1', 'pat2': 'repl2', ...}`. There are various ways of specifying independent replacements (lists, Series, dicts, etc). See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html).

To illustrate the difference,

```
df['A'].str.replace('foo', 'text1').str.replace('bar', 'text2')

0                  text1
1    another text1 text2
2                    baz
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Would be better expressed as

```
df['A'].replace({'foo': 'text1', 'bar': 'text2'}, regex=True)

0                  text1
1    another text1 text2
2                    baz
Name: A, dtype: object
```

---

In the context of string operations, **`str.replace` enables regex replacement by default. `replace` only performs a full match unless the `regex=True` switch is used.**

Everything you do with `str.replace`, you can do with `replace` as well. However, it is important to note the following differences in the default behaviour of both methods.

1. substring replacements - `str.replace` will replace every occurrence of the substring, `replace` will only perform whole word matches by default
2. regex replacement - `str.replace` interprets the first argument as a regular expression unless you specify `regex=False`. `replace` is the exact opposite.

Contrast the difference between

```
df['A'].replace('foo', 'bar')

0                bar
1    another foo bar
2                baz
Name: A, dtype: object
```

And

```
df['A'].replace('foo', 'bar', regex=True)

0                bar
1    another bar bar
2                baz
Name: A, dtype: object
```

It is also worth mentioning that you can *only* perform string replacement when `regex=True`. So, for example, `df.replace({'foo': 'bar', 1: -1}, regex=True)` would be invalid.

---

## TLDR;

To summarise, the main differences are,

> 1. **Purpose**. Use `str.replace` for substring replacements on a single string column, and `replace` for any general replacement on one or more
>    columns.
> 2. **Usage**. `str.replace` can replace one thing at a time. `replace` lets you perform multiple independent replacements, i.e., replace many things
>    at once.
> 3. **Default behavior**. `str.replace` enables regex replacement by default. `replace` only performs a full match unless the `regex=True` switch is used.

Comment: Nice explanation! The thing I like about Dataframe.replace is that it is a DataFrame level method allowing replace across columns. Say there is a '?' inplace of NaN in the entire df.

Comment: @Vaishali Yup, `replace` is very convenient! Although the only thing I haven't touched upon here is the performance aspect of it as I thought to keep it simple. I will expand on that when I have a little more time. :)

Comment: One thing to note is as of pandas 1.2.0 (Dec 26, 2020), the release notes state that "The default value of regex for Series.str.replace() will change from True to False in a future release." So you might want to manually include regex=True if you're using str.replace.  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html#deprecationse

Comment: Great answer. I wanted to expand on this and know why we should not always just use ```replace()``` over ```str.replace()```. The question is at: [StackQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72591227/always-using-pandas-series-method-replace-over-str-replace)

Answer (score 2):

If you are comparing `str.replace` with `replace`, I would assume that you are thinking of replacing strings only.

The two thumb rules that help (especially when using `.apply()` and `lambda`) are:

1. If you want to replace many things at once use `df.replace({dict})`. Remember the defaults as mentioned by `cs95` or in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html).
2. If you want to use regex AND *case sensitivity* options use `str.replace()`: `lambda x: x.str.replace('^default$', '', regex = True, case = False)`.

One final thing to note is that the `inplace` parameter is only available in the `replace` function and not in `str.replace` which may be a deciding factor in your code especially if you are chaining.