# Multiple regex replacements in a loop with pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, loops

I am relatively new to regex and I am trying to replace part of the string inside of the string column in Pandas DataFrame.  The challenge is that I have multiple string types that I want to remove from my column while keeping the rest of the string.

I have code working for 1 type of string, but when I try to use for loop, the code is not working.  I am not sure how to specify iterator inside of the regex expression.

Here is code that works when applied to 1 type of sub-string:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ba ca t', 'foo', 'bait'],'B': ['abc', 'bar', 'xyz']})
df
df=df.replace({'A': r'^ba ca'}, {'A': ''}, regex=True)
df
```

Here is code that is not working when I try to us For Loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ba ca t', 'foo', 'bait'],'B': ['abc', 'bar', 'xyz']})
replace_list=['ba ca','foo']
for i in replace_list:
    df=df.replace({'A': r'^(i)'}, {'A': ''}, regex=True)
df
```

I would like to iterate over a list of strings to remove them from a column in the DataFrame.

Comment: Are you trying to remove those patterns (i.e., replace with empty string '')?

Comment: yes, I am trying to remove them (replace with empty string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you wan't `i` to modify your regex pattern, you should consider this change:

```
 df=df.replace({'A': r'^({})'.format(i)}, {'A': ''}, regex=True)
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------+-----+
|    |  A    |  B  |
+----+-------+-----+
| 0  | t     | abc |
| 1  |       | bar |
| 2  | bait  | xyz |
+----+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 3):

`'^(i)'` is not the correct method of performing string interpolation. You're looking for something along the lines of f-string formatting (`rf'^{i}'`) or `str.format` (`r'^{}'.format(i)`).

Although a better solution here would be to ditch the loop, since `replace` allows you to perform multiple replacements at once.

```
df.replace({'A': replace_list}, '', regex=True)

      A    B
0     t  abc
1        bar
2  bait  xyz
```

Or, with `str.replace`:

```
df['A'].str.replace('|'.join(replace_list), '')

0       t
1        
2    bait
Name: A, dtype: object
```

This post by me should also be worth a read: [What is the difference between Series.replace and Series.str.replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625031/what-is-the-difference-between-series-replace-and-series-str-replace)