# Python Output File Shows Up In Another Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When I run the following, all of the values appear in 1 column:

```
df["abcd"].unique()
```

When I open this same tab delimited file in excel, and delimit by tab, part of the values appear in 1 column (`column_14`) and the rest appear in another (`column_1`) in the next line.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** Added Sample Data

When I look at the data in the abcd column, it looks like this:

```
'John.Doe@example.com / john doe\rsally.sample@example.com / sally sample\rjames.example@example.com',
'homer.simpson@testing.com / homer simpson\r' ...
```

It looks like every value has a carriage return, except for the very last line has both a carriage return and a linefeed value.

When I open this column in Excel, John Doe is in `column_14`, but Sally, and James are both in `column_1`.

Homer Simpson is in `column_14`, but everything after is in `column_1`, until the last line has both a carriage return and a line feed.

I'm guessing I need to either add line feeds to all of the values or return all of the carriage returns?

Edit #2: I believe the problem has to do with carriage returns.

I added the following but it doesn't appear to be working:

```
df["abcd"] = df["abcd"].replace({r'\\r':''}, regex=True)
```

Comment: What is in `df["abcd"]`? In particular are there any things that could be behaving as a delimeter?

Comment: It might be helpful to loop at a few lines of the file in a basic text editor (vim/notepad/etc) to see what is appearing where excel is adding the newline.

Comment: Edited Post to show sample data.

Comment: You want `df["abcd"].str.replace`

Comment: Bingo, that was the problem

Comment: why is that the problem? Why did I have to put ".str." ? The entire column is a text data type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625031/what-is-the-difference-between-series-replace-and-series-str-replace