# Replace characters with a space within a column while maintaining original value (In Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, where, in one column I would like to replace the '.' with a ' ' or space.

note - the Date is an object type

**Data**

```
Date    Type
Q1.27   A
Q2.27   B
```

**Desired**

```
Date    Type
Q1 27   A
Q2 27   B
```

**Doing**

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace('.','', regex=True)
```

However this eliminates the full value. Any suggestion is appreciated. I think I may need to incorporate a split since the code is instructing the value to be replaced by a space.

Comment: Use `regex=False`. In a regular expression, `.` matches any character.

Comment: And `''` should be `' '` -- you need a space there.

Comment: @Barmar ok and this should not delete the actual dates - will try

Comment: hmm ok this did not work- will research...You mentioned str.replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a regular expression, `.` is a wildcard that matches any character. So you're replacing all characters with an empty string. Use `regex=False` to make this a literal string instead of a regular expression.

And you said you wanted the replacement to be a single space, not an empty string.

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace('.',' ', regex=False)
```

Comment: ok for some reason this doesn't work - I still see the Q1.27

Comment: Try with `.str.replace()`

Comment: I thought it would work because your original code worked without `.str`.

Comment: Now I'm not sure why it didn't work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625031/what-is-the-difference-between-series-replace-and-series-str-replace for the difference.

Comment: ok I see the Date column was an object, so we had to convert to str first. thanks!

Comment: Ah, that was not obvious from the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Date'] =df['Date'].str.replace('\.',' ',regex=True)



    Date Type
0  Q1 27    A
1  Q2 27    B
```

Comment: Why use `regex=True` if you're just going to escape everything?

Comment: Just an alternative @Barmar