# How can I remove '\n + 1' from a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have the following dataframe:

| Senior | Location |
| --- | --- |
| False | Warszawa |
| True | Warszawa\n + 1 |

I try to remove that "\n + 1", which looks like a hidden character to me. At first, I tried with:

`df['Location']=df['Location'].str.replace('Warszawa\n + 1','Warszawa')`

but nothing happened.

I managed to remove those characters manually, with a long row of splits and replaces, but it is not a viable solution, because it gives me some weird results in subsequent part of the program: although I have "Warszawa" in both rows of the df, they are treated as being two different locations, although there is only one location.

What I want is this:

| Senior | Location |
| --- | --- |
| False | Warszawa |
| True | Warszawa |

How can I correctly remove that "\n + 1"? And what character is it?

Comment: Is it a newline, or is it the two characters "backslash n"?  That's an important difference.

Comment: You should try `df['Location'].str.replace('Warszawa\\n + 1','Warszawa')`

Comment: Sometimes the double backslash won't work to find an exact match, you could also try it as a string literal `df['Location'].str.replace(r'Warszawa\n + 1','Warszawa')`

Comment: @TimRoberts it is a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.str.replace` method searches for regex (**Reg**ular **Ex**pression) patterns. In regex the `+` has a special meaning. In order to tell pandas, that you are searching for exactly `+`, you need to set `regex = False`.

```
df['Location'] = df['Location'].str.replace(r'Warszawa\n + 1','Warszawa', regex = False)
```

Here you can read more about the parameters:
[pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

You will have same problem if one of following characters are in the column, which you search:

`.`, `[`, `]`, `*`, `?`

For the complete list, search for `regex special characters`

Comment: What's the point of `regex=False`?

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly. Note: This post was flagged as a low-quality post. – [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32000324)

Comment: Now it makes sense. Thank you both you and eHarazi. I'd accept both answers, but I can accept only one.

Comment: Glad it helped. Amir deserves the credit since he pointed out the regex problem first :). Your problem did get me thinking about the two methods so I ended up asking my own question about the two: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72591227/always-using-pandas-series-method-replace-over-str-replace)

Answer (score 1):

When using `str.replace()` the regex parameter is set to `True` by default. Since you just want to replace the literal string you either want to do what @Amir Py has done and turn `regex=False` or you can use the `replace()` method and do an inplace literal string replacement. The regex parameter is `replace()` is set to `False` by default.

Code:

```
df['Location'].replace('Warszawa\n + 1', 'Warszawa', inplace=True)
```

It can also be useful if you have other similar issues in other columns of your dataframe. For more information there is a great question and answer on stack:
[str.replace v replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625031/what-is-the-difference-between-series-replace-and-series-str-replace)