# Always using Pandas Series method replace over str.replace

Tags: python, pandas, replace, series, str-replace

There was a great question and answer about the difference between pandas Series `str.replace()` and `replace()` method:

[stackoverflow.com/difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625031/what-is-the-difference-between-series-replace-and-series-str-replace)

I wanted to expand on this and ask - why not **always** use the `replace()` method when it covers what `str.replace()` does and more? What advantage does `str.replace()` offer over `replace()` when it comes to string replacement in a Series or DataFrame?