# removing special characters from a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have characters such as " ' . , " in a column in my df, and i cannot remove them using the replace() function. I have tried the following

```
df.column_name = df.column_name.replace('/[^a-zA-Z ]/g', '')
```

But the result still has ' in the name.

Example:

```
df:
  id   column_name
0 aaa   sam
1 bbb   joe's
```

Result after running the code:

```
df.column_name = df.column_name.replace('/[^a-zA-Z ]/g', '')
df.head(2)

df:
  id   column_name
0 aaa   sam
1 bbb   joe's
```

I also tried it specifically for ' character by running:

```
df.column_name = df.column_name.replace("'", '')
```

But doesn't work.
Any idea how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: You don't put slashes around regular expressions in Python.

Comment: What is df.column_name?

Comment: BTW, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625031/what-is-the-difference-between-series-replace-and-series-str-replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `/` and `g`, this syntax is not valid in python:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z ]', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
    id column_name
0  aaa         sam
1  bbb        joes
```

Comment: I think `.str.replace()` is preferred in this case. And then it defaults to `regex=True`

Comment: @Barmar yes I had changed it, I noticed when adding the sample, also `str.replace` currently has `regex=True` as default but this will change in the future ;)